# Remove prefix (or suffix) substring from column headers in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to remove the sub string _x that is located in the end of part of my df column names.

**Sample df code:**

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'W_x': ['abcde','abcde','abcde']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['First_x']=[0,0,0]
df['Last_x']=[1,2,3]
df['Slice']=['abFC=0.01#%sdadf','12fdak*4%FC=-0.035faf,dd43','FC=0.5fasff']
```

**output:**

```
     W_x  First_x Last_x                 Slice
0  abcde      0     1                   abFC=0.01
1  abcde      0     2  12fdak*4%FC=-0.035faf,dd43
2  abcde      0     3                 FC=0.5fasff
```

**Desired output:**

```
       W  First  Last                       Slice
0  abcde      0     1                   abFC=0.01
1  abcde      0     2  12fdak*4%FC=-0.035faf,dd43
2  abcde      0     3                 FC=0.5fasff
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I usually use @cs95 way but wrapping it in a data frame method just for convenience:

```
import pandas as pd

def drop_prefix(self, prefix):
    self.columns = self.columns.str.lstrip(prefix)
    return self

pd.core.frame.DataFrame.drop_prefix = drop_prefix
```

Then you can use it as with inverse method already implemented in pandas `add_prefix`:

```
pd.drop_prefix('myprefix_')
```

Comment: Using lstrip like that could remove some characters, for instance "myprefix_mean".lstrip('myprefix_') would return "an" instead of the probably expected "mean". As other suggested in other comments replace is probably better in this case.

Comment: [Python 3.9 added](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#new-string-methods-to-remove-prefixes-and-suffixes) `removeprefix`/`removesuffix`. There's an issue about adding those to pandas `str` ops. Everyone please head over to https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/36944 and upvote.

Answer (score 95):

### python < 3.9, pandas < 1.4

Use `str.strip`/`rstrip`:

```
# df.columns = df.columns.str.strip('_x')
# Or, 
df.columns = df.columns.str.rstrip('_x')  # strip suffix at the right end only.

df.columns
# Index(['W', 'First', 'Last', 'Slice'], dtype='object')
```

To avoid the issue highlighted in the comments:

> Beware of strip() if any column name starts or ends with either _ or
> x beyond the suffix.

You could use `str.replace`,

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'_x$', '')

df.columns
# Index(['W', 'First', 'Last', 'Slice'], dtype='object')
```

---

### Update: python >= 3.9, pandas >= 1.4

From version 1.4, you will soon be able to use [`str.removeprefix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.removeprefix.html#pandas.Series.str.removeprefix)/[`str.removesuffix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.removesuffix.html#pandas.Series.str.removesuffix).

Examples:

```
s = pd.Series(["str_foo", "str_bar", "no_prefix"])
s
0    str_foo
1    str_bar
2    no_prefix
dtype: object

s.str.removeprefix("str_")
0    foo
1    bar
2    no_prefix
dtype: object
```

```
s = pd.Series(["foo_str", "bar_str", "no_suffix"])
s
0    foo_str
1    bar_str
2    no_suffix
dtype: object

s.str.removesuffix("_str")
0    foo
1    bar
2    no_suffix
dtype: object
```

Comment: Same as for another answer, beware of `strip()` if any column name starts or ends with either `_` or `x` beyond the suffix.

Comment: @FabienP if that's an issue, str.replace would be the ideal choice with '_x$' as the pattern.

Comment: Sure, I think it could be advertised in your answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! What would 'r' and '$' indicate in r'_x$'?

Regex and exact match?

Comment: @TheEconomist r is a raw string literal, and $ matches the end of the line.

Comment: How could I apply your solution on a map function? I´ve tried this but does not work : a.columns = map(str.removeprefix('str_prefx'), a.columns)

Answer (score 19):

```
df.columns = [col[:-2] for col in df.columns if col[-2:]=='_x' else col]
```

or

```
df.columns = [col.replace('_x', '') for col in df.columns]
```

Comment: The second approach will replace every occurence, even for a column name 'Last_xmas_x` will be `Lastmas`

Answer (score 16):

I'd suggest to use the [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) function:

```
df.rename(columns = lambda x: x.strip('_x'))
```

Output is as desired

Of yourse you can also take care of FabienP's comment and modify if according to Quang Hoang's solution:

```
df.rename(columns = lambda x: x.replace('_x$', ''))
```

gives the desired output.

Another solution is simply:

```
df.rename(columns = lambda x: x[:-2] if x.endswith('_x') else x)
```

Comment: Beware! Could cause troubles where column's name contains either `_` or `x` at start or end, beyond the suffix `_x`...

Comment: Interesting: do you know why? having a column name like `Last_x_y` does not strip anything, but `Last_x_` and `Last_x_x` gets stripped to `Last`.

Comment: @FabienP, what do you suggest instead?

Comment: This is because `strip` removes any occurences of the provided characters from both ends of the string. It does not consider a pattern, but a sequence of characters.
Likely `replace` is more specific, or some usage of `split`. Like `rsplit('_', 1)[0]` which would be more flexible than replace if suffix changes but does not contain more than one underscore.

Answer (score 4):

**Python=3.8 and Pandas=1.3:**

Use `df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('_x','')` to get rid of the suffix.

This works well and only removes the exact substring(suffix) `'_x'` from the column names as opposed to `str.strip/str.rstrip(substring)` which removes all the characters mentioned in the `substring` from the DataFrame's column names irrespective of whether the complete substring is present in the column name or not, the sequence in which these characters are occurring, etc.

Answer (score 0):

With Python 3.9+ you can use string methods `removesuffix()` and `removeprefix()` as follows:

```
df.columns = df.rename(columns = lambda x: x.removesuffix('_x')) # or any suffix per say
df.columns = df.rename(columns = lambda x: x.removeprefix('prefix_i_want_to_remove'))
```

Or you can directly map onto columns as:

```
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: x.removesuffix('_x')) # or any suffix per say
df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: x.removeprefix('prefix_i_want_to_remove'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar request, needed to strip off a prefix for the columns headers. In my case the prefixes had this pattern: **'p1-', 'p2-', 'p3-'** and so on, so I use the following snippet to remove all of them:

```
df.columns.str.replace(r'[a-z][0-9]*-','')
```