# Using Join in python

Tags: python, sql, pandas, outer-join, code-conversion

I am converting an SQL code, that has a join function, to Python.

This is the SQL code:

```sql
INSERT INTO tropical_fruits
SELECT DISTINCT A.* 
FROM fruits A LEFT OUTER JOIN tropical_fruits B 
ON A.[fruit1] = B.[fruit1] AND A.[fruit2] = B.[fruit2];
```

Python conversion code is:

```py
data = pd.merge(
    fruits, tropical_fruits,
    left_on=['fruit1','fruit2'], 
    right_on=['fruit1','fruit2'], 
    how='left'
)
```

But I haven't got the desired result. Is the Python code correct?

Comment: How did your Python try differ from your SQL try?

Comment: Python code is creating a new column with _x and _y suffix of these two columns 'fruit1','fruit2'.

Comment: `out = fruits.merge(tropical_fruits, on=['fruit1','fruit2'], how='left')`

Comment: It's still creating _x and _y suffix of the 2 columns

Comment: read this post : [pandas-merging-101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101) and If this is not enough, please read the following notice and provide [mre]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55679401/remove-prefix-or-suffix-substring-from-column-headers-in-pandas for how to remove the `_x` suffix from the column names.

Comment: Your LEFT JOIN adds nothing. You can skip it. And why do you want to insert same table data one more time?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
data = fruits.merge(tropical_fruits, on=['fruit1','fruit2'], how='left')
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to avoid _x and _y suffix you should determine the columns that you want in merge for each dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
fruits = pd.DataFrame({'fruit1':['apple', 'banana', 'cherry'],'fruit2':['d','f','h'],'id':[1,2,3]  })
tropical_fruits = pd.DataFrame({'fruit1':['apple', 'banana', 'mango'],'fruit2':['d','n','h'],'id':[1,2,4]})
result=pd.merge(fruits[['fruit1','fruit2','id']], tropical_fruits[['fruit1','fruit2']],  how='left', left_on=['fruit1','fruit2'],right_on=['fruit1','fruit2'])
```